# How can I organize map<set<multiset<int>>,int> in C++ error C2338

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, set

I want to declare

```
map<set<multiset<int>>,int> mymap;
```

but MSVC 2015 gives me this error:

error C2338: The C++ Standard doesn't provide a hash for this type.

How can I supply comparison operator? Probably this is what missing here?

Comment: That is not the actual declaration. Doesn't match the error.

Comment: Either you are actually using a `unordered_something` or msvc's error message is that broken

Comment: On the other side, do you really want such a thing? What kind of a construct is that?

Comment: Whatever you are doing, there is probably a better way to do it. Why do you need a set of multisets mapped to an int?

Comment: Its a set of monomials in a multivariate polynomial.

Comment: You should have no trouble with this definition (Though it is weird). `std::set` and `std::multiset` both define `operator<` so there shouldn't be a problem. Pretty sure you are trying to use an `unordered_map` somewhere.

Comment: Dear @nakiya, yes, this was the rootcause. Please post explaination and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per request,

Most probably you were trying to create `mymap` like so:

```
unordered_map<set<multiset<int>>,int> mymap;
```

The key type for the `unordered_map` is `set<multiset<int>>` which does not define a hash function. But, it does define `operator<`.

So, the definition given in the post should be fine, but you probably were using an `unordered_map`.

P.S. Using `set<multiset<int>>` as a key type for a `map` doesn't feel right. `set::operator<` has O(n) time complexity. `multiset::operator<` is the same. But, if you are not worried about performance, it's fine.